# Omega limit set of omega limit set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $\phi(t;a)$ is a smooth $n$-dimensional flow in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. The omega-limit set of $A$ is defined to be $\omega(A):= \bigcup_{a \in A} \omega(a)$, where $\omega(a)$ is the omega limit set of $a$. 
My question is: if we are given an $a_0 \in A$ and we look at $\omega(\omega(a_0))$, is this set then equal or different than $\omega(a_0)$, and most importantly why?
Thanks in advance!